# Using a template variable that contains a JSON object with Postman Collection Runner

Tags: json, postman, postman-collection-runner

I am attempting to use the Postman collection runner to post several objects to an API from a JSON file structured something like this:

```
[
    {
        "id": "170",
        "body": {
            "name": "prod1",
            "category": "category1"
        },
        "anotherProperty": "xyz"
    },
    {
        "id": "171",
        "body": {
            "name": "prod3",
            "category": "category1"
        },
        "anotherProperty": "dfg"
    },
    {
        "id": "172",
        "body": {
            "name": "prod3",
            "category": "category1"
        },
        "anotherProperty": "abc"
    }
]
```

My problem seems to be with the body since it is an object:

**Here is what I have in the Body > raw application/json of the request that my collection is using:**

```
{
    "$id": "{{id}}",
    "body": {{body}},
    "anotherProperty": "{{anotherProperty}}"
}
```

When viewing what it is plugging in it looks like:

```
{
    "id": "170",
    "body": {[object Object]}, // instead of the actual object
    "anotherProperty": "xyz"
}
```

Answer (score 4):

I needed to add the following to the Pre-request script:

```
let properties = pm.iterationData.get('properties');
pm.variables.set('properties', JSON.stringify(properties));

let body = pm.iterationData.get('body');
pm.variables.set('body', JSON.stringify(body));
```

And the raw JSON is plugged in with no problem!